# void pointer argument, pass buffer

Tags: c++

I've an object buffer implementation which looks like this:

```
class obj_buffer_t
{
public:
    obj_buffer_t(char *heap, size_t size, size_t cnt);
            // Some other stuff
private:
            // Some other stuff
};
```

The record_objbuf is created as static buffer:

```
static obj_buffer_t::buffer_t<obj_buffer_min_heap_size_t< sizeof(Record_XY), RECORD_SIZE>::result> record_buffer;
obj_buffer_t record_objbuf(record_buffer.heap, sizeof record_buffer.heap, RECORD_SIZE);
```

In my program I want to read records and create them within this buffer, but how do I have to call my method?

The method signature is following:

```
Record * getRecord(unsigned & addr, Info & info, void * objbuf = NULL);
```

My call:

```
record = tm.getRecord(p, info, static_cast<obj_buffer_t *>(record_objbuf));
```

Compiler gives me the error: invalid static_cast from type `obj_buffer_t` to type `obj_buffer_t*`

If I don't use a cast at all, I get:

no matching function for call to `getRecord(uint32_t&, Info&, obj_buffer_t&)`

What I'm doing wrong here?

Thx!

Comment: I don't mean this in a mean way, but it seems to me like you are messing with some advanced C++ features before mastering the needed basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 'Invalid static_cast from type obj_buffer_t to type obj_buffer_t* ' means that `record_objbuff` is object itself, not a pointer to that object. Your function needs pointer. So you should use unary `&` operator to get address of the object as a pointer:

```
record = tm.getRecord( p, info, (void*)&record_objbuf );
```

Comment: That's what I wrote in the first place and the compiler still gives me an error message: no matching function for call to 'getRecord(uint32_t&, Info&, obj_buffer_t*)'

Comment: So, let us give a try to `record = tm.getRecord( p, info, (void*)&record_objbuf )`